# Linear program decomposition and Column Generation

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I needed to decompose a large LP of equality constraints.
$\\Dx=B^1,$
$\\Ax=B^2,$ 
$\\D \in R^{m^{(1)} \times n} $
$\\A\in R^{m^{(2)} \times n}, m<<n$

$A$ has a block diagonal structure and $D$ is formed for some link constraints which may span all variables.

I was suggested to use Dantzig-Wolfe Decomposition followed by the Column Generation algorithm.
While reading these, I found that this algorithm uses extreme points of each segment as a starting point and builds all the feasible points in the segment as a convex combination of these extreme points.
What I don't understand is how can we assume to have all these extreme points. Is there a computationally efficient way of doing this? Or is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A description of the method often starts with the full set of extreme points (and extreme rays), but these are typically generated dynamically via a *column generation* subproblem.  In practice, only a small subset of all possible extreme points (and extreme rays) are needed.  You can use a two-phase approach (like in the simplex method), where the first phase finds a feasible solution and the second phase finds an optimal solution.  If you can otherwise construct a set of columns that together yield a feasible master solution, you can skip the first phase.

Comment: Can using Dantzig decomposition without using col gen. improve the efficiency of a linear programming problem?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. Enumerate all columns up front and then solve the (unrestricted) master problem once?